# show that there exists a function in the dual space such that it's bounded and equal to the inf norm

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space, $W \subset V$ a subspace. Let $v \in V-W$. Let $d=\{\inf \lVert w-v \rVert : w\in W\}$ be the distance between $v$ and $W$. Prove that there exists a $l\in V^*$ such that $\lVert l \rVert \leq 1, l(v)=d$ and $l(w)=0$ for all $w \in W$.

I'm not sure how to start.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If $d=0$ there is nothing to prove, so assume $d>0$, in which case you can replace $W$ by $\overline{W}$ to assume that $W$ is itself closed.

Pass to the quotient space $V/W$, then $d = \|\pi(v)\|$ where $\pi$ is the quotient map. So, there exists $f \in (V/W)^{\ast}$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(\pi(v)) = d$ by Hahn-Banach.

Now take $l := f\circ \pi$. This will work.

Comment: Hi, I understand that by Hahn Banach we have $\Vert v \Vert _{\frac{V}{W}} = \sup \{ |f(v)| : f \in (\frac{V}{W})^*, \Vert f \Vert _{(\frac{V}{W})^*}=1 \} \forall v \in \frac{V}{W} $ . But why is $f(\pi(v))=d$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $W$ is closed. First we define $\def\span{\text{span}}f: \span\{v,W\}\to \mathbb F$ as follows. ($\mathbb F=\mathbb R \text{ or }\mathbb C$.) Since for all $x\in \span (v,W)$, there exists a unique scalar $k$ and a unique vector $w\in W$ such that $x=kv+w$. We define $f(x)=kd$.

**Claim.**  $|f(x)|\leq d(x,W)\leq \|x\|$.

This is quite easy to prove: 
$$|f(x)|=|k|d=|k|d(v,W)=d(kv,W)=d(kv+w,W)=d(x,W)
$$
by the definition of distance $d(v,W)$. Now, by Hahn-Banach theorem, we can extend $f$ to $l\in V^\ast$ so that $|l(x)|\leq \|x\|$. $l$ is the desired linear functional. ($l$ is clearly continuous because it is bounded by $\|x\|$.)